# Using Vue.js components in PHP apps

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, components, vue-router

I am using PHP and Vue.js with vue-router. I've got a php form handler that sends emails. I would like to redirect the user to a certain component from my vue app when the email is sent. Is there a way to make it work? I created a component Thankyou.vue and would like to somehow embed it in my php file.

```
if(mail($address, $msg, $headers)) {
    header("Location: http://mypage.com/thankyou");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with vue.js, so don't nail me down on the JS part :-)

Anyway, what you should do is POST your data to PHP with AJAX and return JSON and correct HTTP headers.

POST the data in JavaScript and handle the response promise:

```
this.$http.post('//someurl.bla', { key: value })
    .then((response) => {
      // show your thank you message
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Handle errors in PHP:

```
/**
 * exits the script and returns a HTTP 400 and JSON error message
 * @param str $msg error message
 */
function dieError($msg) {
    http_response_code('400');
    echo json_encode(['error' => $msg]);
    exit;
}

// check form data
if (!$_POST['parameter']) {
    dieError('Parameter "Parameter" is missing.');
}
// do stuff, build the mail content etc.

// throw an error if the mail is not sent (note the !)
if(!mail($address, $msg, $headers)) {
    dieError('Error sending mail');
}

// if the script arrives here, everything was fine, the status code will be 200 OK
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But do you think in this part: `.then((response) => { // show your thank you message })` am I able to redirect the user using the routing made with vue.js?

Comment: And if it's not a problem, what should I use instead of `//someurl.bla`, the url of my own page, right?

Comment: You should be able to redirect using `router.push()`. The first parameter of `post()` is the URL of your PHP script.

Comment: I created a method and bound it to my submit button. I changed the url and added `router.push()`.
     `this.$http.post('../../index.php', { key: value })`
And still I get `cannot read property 'post' of undefined` and `Cannot POST`, what should I change?

Comment: `cannot read property 'post' of undefined` means that `this.$http` is not defined. Without seeing your JS code, I can't even guess why this is. Also, as I said, I am not too familiar with Vue.js, but this example looks pretty straight forward: https://codepen.io/tutelagesystems/pen/pjBbxQ If you still have troubles, post another question with your JS code and ask the vue.js experts for help :)